# Active states not being retained on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

After click the menu button maintain the hover and active color

```js
$('.menu-item a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu-item {
    list-style: none;
} 
.menu-item a {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1B3E70;
    color: #1B3E70;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
    background-color: #1B3E70;
    color: white;
}
.menu-item .active{
    background-color: #1B3E70;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="check.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="checking.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>  
</head>

<body>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">jerome</a>
        <a href="#">ibrahim</a>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this link if jquery is added  ..it is working  http://jsfiddle.net/nscmwokf/2/

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/eq5rzrq3/ check your console for error

Comment: i try thz its not working i dont knw whr is th problem,can u giv the solved program in one html file

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should add Jquery library first. :\</strike>

The code that you have with you is alright. The problem must be with the linked Jquery library. Check whether the path to that file is right or wrong. You can use the network resources tab in console to track it down.

```js
$('.menu-item a').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu-item {
  list-style:none;
 } 

.menu-item a{
     padding:20px;
     padding-bottom:10px;
     border:1px solid #1B3E70;
     color:#1B3E70;
     text-decoration:none;
 }
 .menu-item a:hover{
      background-color:#1B3E70;
      color:white;
  }
  .menu-item .active{
       background-color:#1B3E70;
       color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="check.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="checking.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>  
    </head>

    <body>
    <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">jerome</a>
                <a href="#">ibrahim</a>
     </li>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1) You've put jQuery outside the `<html>` tag and 2) jQuery 1.8.0 is already included in OPs code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I confused while using the in built code tool. :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited the answer in a way that would be useful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine. [Here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/h7fbsno1/)

Two chances are there not to work your code

1) You didn't call jQuery in head properly.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2) You didn't use `$( document ).ready()`for loading jQuery.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //add your code here
});
```

OR

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    //add your code here
});
```

Comment: I gave two options might issue with any of these options.

Comment: @Runcorn it is if the script is included in the `head` of the document, as OPs appears to be.

Comment: still its not working man...when i open my jquery library file, it's show the security popup thn i click open button then only its open. i think that is the problem behind thiz.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative path for Jquery file.
start from root.

if jquery in root use

/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

if have inside folder like JS folder - then use

/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

try putting your click binding function in document ready function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-item a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
)};
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="check.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="check.css">
```

Comment: What possible difference will swapping the order of inclusions for a stylesheet and a script make?